# Why does legend not appear when the first bar value is zero?

Tags: charts, forena

I have created a chart using [Forena reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena). I have added the legend by using the property frx:legend_entries="legend" from the frx file.
But when value of the first bar chart is zero or null, legend is not visible.

I am attaching the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would check the results you'd get by using either of these special settings in the SVG Graph library:

- Use the (boolean) [force_associate](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-dimensions.php#force-assoc) option.
- Set the [axis_min_v](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-dimensions.php#example-1) option to something like `-1`.

If none of these options help, you might have discovered "some issue" (bug?) in the [SVG Graph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) library.

A possible work around might also be that you can think of a way to replace the "zero or null" with "NULL".

Comment: Just curious what the current status of your issue in your question is, and if my answer helped in any way ...